# Is there an easy way to READ ULS programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, logging, uls

I want to read the ULS of Sharepoint, and Filter Items by its Level (Exception,Unexpected,Critical) to display a linechart of errorcount in a certain timeinterval.

Google just showed me a bunch of ways to add new Entries or get a specific Entry.

So - I need to parse each logfile on my own or is there a built-in way I am missing here?

Maybe the best approach is to look into the Code of Sharepoint LogViewer and extract what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SP2013 check [SPULSRetriever class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj168066.aspx)

usage:

`var entries = new SPULSRetriever(forwardCheckTimeInMinutes, maxEntries, DateTime startTime).GetULSEntries(new Guid(correlationId));`

For SP2010 you can check answer to this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101699/get-uls-log-records-programatically)

Comment: Yeah, already found this one.

Won't give me each Entry though, cause I need to specify the CorrelationID. So..this won't help me.